# Can we ask questions by tagging someone personally?

Tags: discussion

There are many users in Hinduism SE. Can some one specifically ask a question to someone by writing his username.

Example : can Darknight(me) ask a question to "jack"(another user).

**Note :"jack" is a random name. It isn't real user**.

Comment: Use a chatroom instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't tag someone in a question like what is possible for *comments* (but only if the user interacted with the post in some way). [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/295232) lists some options to contact a specific user, e.g. via chat.